# RTMP streaming with OSMF - AS3

Tags: actionscript-3, osmf

New to OSMF and trying to play a streaming mp4 on our limelight server. According to this tutorial http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flash/articles/video_osmf_streaming.html, you simply pass the RTMP link to the URLResource. I've tried that and it isn't working. It plays fine if I pass a local URL. I am using OSMF 1.5 SWC and my code is

```
package 
{
    import flash.display.*;
    import flash.events.*;
    import org.osmf.media.*;

    public class Main extends Sprite
    {
        private var mps:MediaPlayerSprite;

        public function Main()
        {
            stage.align     = StageAlign.TOP_LEFT;
            stage.scaleMode = StageScaleMode.NO_SCALE;

            mps             = new MediaPlayerSprite();
            mps.width       = 640;
            mps.height      = 360;
            mps.resource    = new URLResource("rtmp://my.limelight.host.net/mp4:dyk_seatbelts_high.mp4");
            addChild(mps);
        }
    }
}
```

I dont get any errors just a blank canvas. Any ideas?

Comment: well it would be `mps.mediaPlayer.play()` and yes I have tried that. With a local file, it automatically plays so I figured an RTMP link would be no different.

Comment: If I remember correctly there are functions on limelight server that need to be called when you make the NetStream connection. Sorry its been about 2 years and I can't remember what I did and I don't have the code.

Comment: you know, limelight does have a plugin made for OSMF and I have it (it is just an empty swf with a bunch of code in it), but not sure how to use the plugin with OSMF. I am still researching this. Thanks for the help so far

Comment: Weird ok, I have successfully got an FLV to play through limelight..using an MP4 isn't working though. I used the same exact code as above, but instead tried to use an FLV. Also it loads the same wether I do `new URLResource` or `new SteamingURLResource`

Comment: Maybe you encoded the mp4 wrong?

Comment: No, my standard net stream player that I created from scratch plays the mp4 just fine.

Comment: Your best bet is to call support. They have a good team there and will work with you on it.

Comment: yeah I am going to have to..I got seamless stream switching working with the flv versions which is cool..need to use MP4s though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should add streamer and video url for RTMP streaming. For example:

```
var resource:DynamicStreamingResource = new DynamicStreamingResource(videoStreamer);
resource.urlIncludesFMSApplicationInstance = true;
var vector:Vector.<DynamicStreamingItem> = new Vector.<DynamicStreamingItem>(1);
vector[0] = new DynamicStreamingItem(videoUrl, 1200);
resource.streamItems = vector;
element = new VideoElement(resource);

player.media = element;
```

You can add few dynamic streaming items. Video files with different bitrate.

Example for **videoStreamer**: rtmp://streamer_url

Example for **videoUrl**: mp4:path_to_video.mp4

Comment: Just in case it helps anyone, you can use the resource that @ExtremeBt creates as the source for a video player
myVideoPlayer.source = resource;

Comment: Yes, also you can use as on the code: player.media = element, the 'player' can be MediaPlayerSprite, MediaPlayer or StrobeMediaPlayer.

Answer (score 2):

This is just an update. The DynamicStreamingItem is not available anymore. You can simply add your rtmp stream url to a StreamingURLResource. Plays like a charm. (Correct me if i'm wrong....i'm new to OSMF)

```
var videoElement:VideoElement = new VideoElement();
videoElement.resource = new StreamingURLResource("rtmp://cp140972.XXXXX",StreamType.LIVE,NaN,NaN,null,false);
player.media = videoElement;
```